# Error when submit spark application in datastax enterprise

Tags: datastax-enterprise, spark-submit

I got this bug when trying to submit app from master node: 
**dse -u abc -p abc spark-submit --confpark.cassandra.auth.username=abc --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=abc --conf spark.debug.maxToStringFields=10000 --conf spark.executor.memory=4G app.py**

Im using 3 dse analytics node, 1 datacenter, 4 core/16gb ram node and submit app from master node. When I go to check tasks/stages I saw this bug:

[image]

Does everybody have even seen this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your application that writes data into your tables - either it deletes a lot of data, or (most probably) it inserts nulls as part of "normal" inserts - in this case the tombstones are generated, and if you have a lot of them, the query are starting to fail.

What you can do:

- stop inserting nulls as part of data. If you're using Spark to write data, maybe run job with `--conf spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls=true` - this will prevent writing nulls, but this may not work very well with overwriting existing data. If you're using other driver(s), use `unset` for fields that have null value;
- don't delete data by individual columns, but delete by rows/ranges/partitions
- expire tombstones much faster - if you can, maybe use lower `gc_grace_period`, but this comes with its own challenges - I recommend to read [this article](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html) for better understanding of the problem.